# MongoDB query/cursor repeating itself in Python and Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

The code below is looping twice. I have no idea why.

```
 # Test Mongo Query
 import mongo

 # Connect To Mongo
 from pymongo import MongoClient
 client = MongoClient()

 db = client.racing
 people = db.people

 cursor = db.people.find_one({"age":6})

 print(cursor['birth_date'])
```

The output Python generates is the birthdate twice in a row. I noticed this issue first when running a "find" query (not a find_one)... and it seems to be doing the same thing for just find_one as well.

```
 >>> 
 06/08/2007
 06/08/2007
 >>>
```

The first handful of visits to Dr. Google didn't yield much... any thoughts?

Comment: Just tested -- everything work fine, printed one string. Windows 7/Python 2.7.4/pymongo 2.5.2. BTW, you typed `import mongo` but should `import pymongo`, guess it's a typo...

Comment: That was exactly it. Total typo. In doing so, it was using both to run it twice. How sad I didn't catch that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, the issue was the typo after "import." It was creating two separate "connections" and thus running it twice through the cursor.

```
 import pymongo
```

instead of..

```
 import mongo
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 from pymongo import MongoClient
 client = MongoClient()
 db=client['racing']
 cursor = db.people.find_one({"age":6})

 print cursor['birth_date']
```

Don't need import mongo, only pymongo for all